# how to read csv file and put its value in checkbox?

Tags: php, csv

i upload a csv file and i get the file name and path of file i want to read csv file and put csv values in check box,here is my code:

```
$fu=uploadUserFile('uploadcsv', false, true, 'csv_', 'csv');
print_r($fu);
```

this array show result given below:

```
Array ( [error] => [filepath] => C:/wamp/www/ticket_inspector_new/useruploads_hd87wblfo084wgdtry/ [filename] => csv_0988310001391870698.csv ) 

<input type="checkbox" name="receptionts[]" checked="checked" value="monica.monaca@hotmail.com"/> Hassan Nazir
```

my csv file contain:

```
"Hassan Nazir","monica.monaca@hotmail.com"
"Hassan Nazir","monica.monaca@hotmail.com"
"Hassan Nazir","monica.monaca@hotmail.com"
"Hassan Nazir","monica.monaca@hotmail.com"
"Hassan Nazir","monica.monaca@hotmail.com"
```

Comment: Where are you reading the file, is `uploadUserFile` supposed to return an error? You need to add more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$file = $fu['filepath'].$fu['filename'];
$handle = fopen($file, "r"));
while($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1024)){
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='receptionts[]' value='".$row[1] ."' /> ".
         $row[0]." <br />";
}
```

Comment: how to get the file path from array?

Comment: when i used your code it gives me error Warning: fgetcsv() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in C:\wamp\www\ticket_inspector_new\

Comment: Try `var_dump(file_exists($file))` and tell me what result do you get

Comment: i dont understand what you say

Comment: try `var_dump(file_exists($file))` after `$file=...`

Comment: again same error http://stackoverflow.com/users/2153274/alireza-fallah

Comment: Warning: fgetcsv() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in C:\wamp\www\ticket_inspector_new\forms_hd87wblfo084wgdtry\form_message_confirm.php on line 73

Comment: Try `var_dump(file_exists($file));die;` after `$file=...`

Comment: when i ued var_dump(file_exists($file));die; error remove and show bool(true)

Comment: I added a line, try this and you will be fine

Comment: thanks very much Alireza Fallah